# mysql order by date get 10 result back then order by id again

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

In my current method, I use `order by date` in sql query, then set the `back results` as a new array, sort array by id via `php`.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE 
(
MATCH (title,content) 
AGAINST ('+$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) 
order by date DESC 
limit 0,10
```

I wanna to ask, Is there a sql method, first `order by date` get 10 result back then in these 10 results, `order by id` again, `just in one sql query`?

Comment: I think you mean this:                                            SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column1, column2

Comment: @davidjwest: If I understand correctly, no, he doesn't. In your query, `column2` is relevant only if `column1` is same. OP wants to select top 10 dates, then *resort* them by `id` (ignoring dates).

Comment: Wait, do you want it ordered by date and then id per date? EDIT @Amadan: thats what I thought

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap an outer query around your current query.

```
SELECT q.* 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM table 
          WHERE 
          (
          MATCH (title,content) 
          AGAINST ('+$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
          ) 
          order by date DESC
          limit 0,10) q
   ORDER BY q.id
```

Comment: I _think_ he wants to **resort** by id rather than sort by both.

Comment: @ChrisPatrick: That's exactly what the outer `ORDER BY q.id` does.

Comment: Scratch that, I completely misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE ...
  ORDER BY date DESC
  LIMIT 10
)
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a comma followed by another column to order by:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 
(MATCH (title,content) 
AGAINST ('+$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
order by date, id DESC 
limit 0,10
```